# Halt sed after first replacement

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm writing a script and I need to search for months in a line, eg 01, 02..., 12 and replace it with its abbreviation. However, though I need to search for all months, I only need to replace the first instance of a month number that I find. For instance, if we have a line that looks like this:

05 06 07

I need sed to perform the following:

May 06 07

The current command I'm using produces:

May Jun Jul

Which is not desirable. Here's what I'm using:

```
 date=$(echo $line |cut -d , -f 1 | sed 's/-/ /g;s/:00//;s/:/ /g;s/01/Jan/;s/02/Feb/;s/03/Mar/;s/04/April/;s/05/May/;s/06/Jun/;s/07/Jul/;s/08/Aug/;s/09/Sep/;s/10/Oct/;s/11/Nov/;s/12/Dec/')
```

Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: You should definitely use gnu [tag:date] rather than the super long regex.

Comment: Try putting a caret `^` before the numbers in the sed expression. You will end up with something like `date=$(echo $line |cut -d , -f 1 | sed 's/-/ /g;s/:00//;s/:/ /g;s/^01/Jan/;s/^02/Feb/;s/^03/Mar/;s/^04/April/;s/^05/May/;s/^06/Jun/;s/^07/Jul/;s/^08/Aug/;s/^09/Sep/;s/^10/Oct/;s/^11/Nov/;s/^12/Dec/')`

Comment: Only problem with the caret (`^`) is if i.e. "05 06 07" appears in the middle of the line -- since `^` indicates at the start of the line.

Comment: Add t; after each s/99/Aaa/ (not needed for last one). This make the script going to end if substitute is made. But due to your sed procedure, it change the first occurence that it found, not the first number (so 03 01 07 change 01 to Jan and not 03 to Mar as wanted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with gnu date

```
echo "05 06 07" | while read -r mon rest
do
  mon=$(date -d "2014-$mon-01" +%b)
  echo $mon $rest
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
> echo $line
foo foo05 06 07 foo 02
> [[ $line =~ [0-9]{2}' '[0-9]{2}' '[0-9]{2} ]] && date -d $(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" | tr ' ' '/') '+%b %d %y' 
May 06 07
```

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward, but it seems to work:

```
... sed 's/-/ /g;s/:00//;s/:/ /g
s/01/Jan/
t
s/02/Feb/
t
s/03/Mar/
t
s/04/April/
t
s/05/May/
t
s/06/Jun/
t
s/07/Jul/
t
s/08/Aug/
t
s/09/Sep/
t
s/10/Oct/
t
s/11/Nov/
t
s/12/Dec/'
```

Comment: Not quite. if input is something like 06 05 07 or 07 06 04 and you'll get something like 06 May 07 or 07 06 Apr respectively.

Comment: @alvits: Damn, you're right. And the solution you put in your comment above is better all around, and obvious in hindsight. (Is there a word for "facepalm" + "why didn't I think of that?")